# Which code trolling questions are worth keeping?

Tags: discussion, code-trolling

It looks like [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling)'s [days are numbered](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1514/we-need-to-take-an-official-stance-on-code-trolling/). There seems to be overwhelming consensus that the tag is bad for the site, and should be removed.

Before we stamp it out, there are a few things that need to happen. One of them is deciding which [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) questions to keep around. Just like SO keeps [old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke) around that would be deleted in a heartbeat today, there's no reason not to keep some [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) questions around for their historical significance.

Or maybe you think we should purge them all. That's okay too.

There are only **23** [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) questions on the site. Since that's not a very large number, that allows us to get the community's opinion on whether each individual question should be kept and given a historical lock (effectively preventing almost any action on the post) or deleted.

### [If you'd like your voice to be heard, this is the link for you.](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1iQf4108JB5D18gGbxPyAekwpvHlX5xqhUhsPI5fCzHg/viewform)

Every [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) question on the site is listed on that page with three options: **Keep**, **Delete**, or **Indifferent**. If you want the post to be kept (and to get a historical lock), select **Keep**. If you want it to be deleted, click **Delete**. Otherwise, click **Indifferent**. Repeat that process another 22 times, and click submit. Your choices will be added to the spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WNc7jOkW46WdgroLqzYsEL81OA-ddRN4K8yaBaATFPQ/edit#gid=178826842), which will be taken into account when the actual decisions are made.

I feel like that should be stressed: This vote is *not* solely to determine what questions will be deleted, but it will be used as an indicator of the community's opinion when choosing them.

The choices will be made soon, so get your votes in ASAP! (Really, there's only 23 questions. It doesn't take long.)

If you want to be involved with more than just voting, join us in [the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14385/the-great-code-trolling-purge-of-2014) to organise/discuss the next steps for dealing with code trolling.

Comment: Too dramatic. Contains links that will likely be broken in a couple of years. Can't a post about code-trolling be simple and to the point?

Comment: It is important to note that kept questions will be locked (if I understood this correctly).

Comment: Correct, @Quincunx. I'm about to make an edit that will clarify this (and possibly other stuff; I'm on mobile so I can't be sure)

Comment: @undergroundmonorail I've changed the date that this plan is going ahead to just a generic "soon." I see no reason to be so hasty in doing this.

Comment: Why not use StackExchange’s internal capabilties for this? Make a meta post where answers correspond to nominations for questions (which then can contain arguments) and people agreeing or disagreeing on a nomination can up- or downvote the corresponding answer.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft It would be much more difficult to collect data from 23 SE posts, and, for example, [make fancy graphs](http://mniip.com/misc/codetrolling_poll_stats.png) out of them. Also, I'm pretty sure posting 23 answers would take much longer than making a form (rate limits) and raise quite a few automatic flags. (Not to mention the fact that undergroundmonorail here probably doesn't want 23 useless answers on his meta account.)

Comment: I love the idea of code trolling, but…  
It seems that it must go. Goodbye, code trolling… :(

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I believe that most of code trolling questions should be removed. There is a one exception I've voted for, but otherwise, I believe they are just awful. **This is just my personal opinion,** it doesn't represent the community.

- [I need a program where the user inputs an array of doubles and the program outputs the array sorted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16226/3103) - should be locked with https://stackoverflow.com/q/9033/736054 reason, or if you are too lazy to visit the linked question, the following reason. The reasoning is that it was a good code trolling question, but it also caused everybody to follow it.

  > This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed.

  If you are going to completely remove [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling), please rollback to [revision 7](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/16226/7) (which included the description of category in post (the tag will be removed, and the post will be too confusing with a link to category that doesn't exist)), but preserving the title from [revision 9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/16226/9).
- [Trolling the troll](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/23614/3103) - I have to admit, I changed the tags on the question when I figured out the code trolling is going to be deleted. Anyway, it's clearly [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded), not [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling), even when the title involves "trolls". Do not close, do not delete.
- Everything else - delete. Those questions aren't worth to be simply closed. I will miss points from [Code trolling - Find the question to an answer (42)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16447/3103), but it's for the better.
- [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) tag. Burninate. It will have never happened.