# What is the difference between underhanded and code-trolling?

Tags: discussion, code-trolling, underhanded

PCG [no longer permits code-trolling](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1514/we-need-to-take-an-official-stance-on-code-trolling), but there is another category called [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/underhanded/info), of which the tag wiki currently reads:

> An underhanded challenge is a challenge to write a program that looks as if it is doing one thing, but does something else. For example, a program that outputs the digits of pi up until the 100th decimal place, when it does something else, might be underhanded if it conceals its doing so.

Some discussion was raised at [my post on a buggy hello world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/29959/4897) as to whether this should be closed/downvoted for being a code-trolling question.  What is the difference between underhanded and code-trolling?

Comment: To answer your specific question, underhanded as a concept is a lot more *generic* in that you don't necessarily have to write code to "troll" the user - you just have to accomplish something that is not obvious from reading the code. At the same time, a good underhanded question should be a lot more *specific* (giving a very clear spec of what to hide and what the could should seem to be) than code trolling, which only derailed into "write *any* code whatsoever as long as it has something to do with X".