# Are key-logger questions allowed?

Tags: discussion

I think the term "malicious" is not properly defined with regards to the intent of this community (please refer to: [Should asking for malicious code be on topic?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4829/should-asking-for-malicious-code-be-on-topic)).

Do key-loggers qualify as malicious?

Comment: What do you mean by *key-logger questions*? Where is *malicious* used where you think it is not properly defined? Are you sure you're not talking about *stackoverflow.com* or some similar site?

Comment: @flawr I believe [this is the context for this question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4829/8478).

Comment: Yes, I edited the question to refer to the context.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Depends

This depends but to me it boils down to one thing:

If the scope of the question is to make a keylogger covert, then I would say it's malicious.

Comment: Okay, fair play

Comment: I agree, because answers could be used by others for malicious purposes.