# We can continue code trolling! (NOT A COMMUNITY CONSENSUS)

Tags: discussion, code-trolling

About 9 years ago, every question about [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) was locked and asking new questions about this topic was banned. If you missed this, [I created a subreddit for this](https://www.reddit.com/r/codetrolling/), and hopefully we can make it to Stack Exchange! I will make a proposal on Area 51 soon.

Answer (score 10):

### This is a bad idea

Firstly, read [We need to take an official stance on code trolling](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1514/66833), cause, well, it explains better than I could why [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) is a *very* poor fit for the Stack Exchange model.

Secondly, don't make a proposal on Area 51 - it's gonna get closed as soon as you do. That said, a subreddit isn't a bad call; of all the places code trolling might be appreciated, Reddit is a decent option.

[code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) has been dead and banned for almost a *decade* now, and for good reason. In short, it is close to impossible to consistently write quality [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) questions, and the *rare* few that do work aren't even good fits for CGCC, even with our loose fit into the SE model. If you wanna do some [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling), do it in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte). Anything on main will be closed, and there's zero chance an entire site will be created by it, given that [the entire network dislikes it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214061/trolls-in-our-halls).